# Import a module from a sub package not working

Tags: python, import

My file structure is

```
project/
    __init__.py
    features/
        __init__.py
        CompareText.py
    tests/
        test.py
```

in test.py I am trying to import CompareText

```py
from project.features import CompareText
```

I get an error of:

> ```
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'features'`
> ```

I checked the documentation and I think my import statement is correct. How can I fix it?

Comment: Is the parent of `project` in `sys.path`? You could write a setup.py that makes the project installable and then install it. It could be `python setup.py develop` for instance.

Comment: Are you running test.py as a script, (python test.py) or as an import from another script?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please format your code properly, [click here to learn how](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Your import statement is supposed to look like this :
(But make sure your working directory is the same directory as your project folder is located during execution)

```
    from project.features import CompareText
```

This is supposed to work if your current path while executing the script has the project folder

If you execute it while inside project folder you can use:

```
    from .features import CompareText
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You ran it and it worked? The problem is that top level scripts (e.g., `python test.py`) aren't in packages and don't have any idea of relative imports.

Comment: Please check the changes I have made to my answer.Now it is clearer and will work

Comment: Python doesn't use the current working directory to find packages and modules, although it does use the top level script's directory. These changes still shouldn't work. Have you built the hierarchy and tested it?

Answer (score 0):

Add an `__init__` file in `test`. Your project directory should look like this:

```
project/
    __init__.py
    features/
        __init__.py
        CompareText.py
    tests/
        __init__.py
        test.py
```

Then in `project/tests/test.py` the following import statement will work:

```
from ..features import CompareText
```

Oh, and this will still raise an error if you try to run it directly. In the question you said you tried to import it like this:

```
from project.features import CompareText
```

This will only work if the parent directory of `project` is in Python's module search path. So, if you want to run the tests directly then modify the module search path as needed (See: `sys.path`).

Comment: But if the parent of `project` is in the path, OP's original code works. And since it won't work if you run `test.py` as a script, it may defeat the point of it being a test in the first place.

Comment: but why would it only work if the parent directory of project is in the python's path module. does python search the project file as it has __int__.py file>

Comment: that's the error i get when what you said /// ImportError: Failed to import test module: test_text
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/unittest/loader.py", line 154, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
  File "/Users/wmoz/Desktop/assistant/tests/test_text.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ..features import CompareText
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are running `test.py` as a script. `test.py` needs to find the `project` package and two ways to do that are to make your project installable or to hack `sys.path`.

**Installable**

First, change your directory structure a bit so that project is a subdirectory of some anonymous directory you happen to be using for development. If you are checking this stuff into source control, it needs to be written so that it can be checked out anywhere. Move `tests` down one directory.

```
mydevdir/
    setup.py
    project/
        __init__.py
        features/
            __init__.py
            CompareText.py
    tests/
        test.py
```

How write a `setup.py`. This can get quite complicated. You can read [Building and Distributing Packages with Setuptools](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#building-and-distributing-packages-with-setuptools) and lookup other resources on the net, but a minimalist setup.py is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='project',
      version='0.1',
      description='This is project: project',
      packages=find_packages(),
     )
```

Now, while in `mydevdir` do `python setup.py develop`. Or you can actually produce an install package and put it in a virtual env for test.

**Hack sys.path**

It may be easier to hack paths in `test.py`. Note that this will need to be undone if you make `project` installable later. Just add to the top of `test.py`

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
sys.path.insert(0, str(Path(__file__).absolute().parents[2]))
```

This puts the parent directory in the python path and now `project` will be found on import. It runs the risk that a .py file in the same directory as `project` can mask an installed module. If you have a local `csv.py` and you `import csv`, you'd get the local.